# What is the best practice in wordpress for Themes folder structure?

Tags: wordpress

I just do not understand this bothe folder structure -> 1. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/organizing-theme-files/ , 2. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/block-theme-setup/

best obligatory best practice.

which one do I have to take if I have a static home page, a navigation bar where I link to the Blog that has details page, to private projects with details, with projects from work days with details, mission and more?

or do I put both together?

Have I missed anything else on the Doc Site?

Comment: Your question is actually off-topic in stack overflow, as is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It may be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers, or deleted.